# Make space between two p in the same row (flexbox)

Tags: html, css

```css
#imprint {
    background-color: black;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    padding: 15px;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<article id="imprint">
    <p>test</p>
    <p>test</p>
</article>
```

How can make some space between this two p tags? I haven't found a solution to this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`column-gap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/column-gap) is what you're looking for.

```css
#imprint {
  background-color: black;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 15px;
  justify-content: center;
  
  /* add a gap */
  column-gap: 20px;
}
```

```html
<article id="imprint">
  <p>test</p>
  <p>test</p>
</article>
```

Alternatively, you can just give the `p` elements some horizontal `padding`:

```css
#imprint {
  background-color: black;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 15px;
  justify-content: center;
}

#imprint p {
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<article id="imprint">
  <p>test</p>
  <p>test</p>
</article>
```

Comment: Or you can just add `gap:20px;` to create space the elements without specifying row or column

Comment: @Only use that if you explicitly want that behaviour.